# Co-Founder, Co-founder, or cofounder?

Tags: word-choice, orthography, capitalization, hyphenation, professions

I've seen all three used and there doesn't seem to be a definitive one that I can find. I'm hedging towards Co-Founder as it's a title, but any clarity would be appreciated.

**Edit**

If it makes it any clearer, the intended use would be for business cards; so something like:

> Name Surname
>   Co-Founder Some Company

Comment: Check out [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cofounder%2Cco+-+founder&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) and [When is it necessary to use a hyphen in writing a compound word?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/10041) and [Should “head teacher” be capitalized, when it's not really anyone's occupation](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60519/10041)

Comment: Updated my answer based on your edit

Answer (score 44, accepted):

All are acceptable, so you should follow your judgement.

British usage generally favours rather more hyphens than American usage; I'd use *co-founder* since *cofounder* doesn't look all that natural.  I'd omit the hyphen in *landowner*, though, so it depends.

Longman and Collins tend to prefer unhyphenated while Chambers, predictably, insists on the hyphenated form.

If you're using the word in a title (in which you can capitalize every important word) or at the beginning of a sentence, you should always use *Co-founder*, not *Co-Founder*; such as:

> The Importance of the Co-founder in Contemporary America

For all other usages, just use *co-founder*.

Comment: can you explain why you don't capitalise the 'f' in founder? that's pretty much the one thing i'm not sure on

Comment: Because _founder_ isn't a proper noun. When the hyphenated word (i.e. _Co-founder_) is not in a title, there's no need to capitalize every main word - you only capitalize proper nouns (names, places, etc.)

Comment: Is possible to write "Co Founder" (or "Co founder") as well? Thanks

Comment: Dear @Schovi: No.

Answer (score 9):

Co-founder. Once hyphenated, the word is a single word, so only needs a capital at the beginning of the entire word. If you write Co Founder (which isn't really a word) then you'd capitalize both. co-founder works in a sentence when it's not part of someone's title. So:

Sentence: Elizabeth is the co-founder of the company.
Title: Elizabeth Jones, Co-founder

[IMHO and American experience/prior and very ancient education]

Answer (score 4):

Is it an actual title of address, like someone would be called, "Co-Founder Jones" in the same sense that someone would be called "Mayor Jones"?

If not, if it's simply the name of a job or role, like "engineer" or "accountant", then it is not capitalized. You write, "Bob is one of our co-founders," not "Bob is one of our Co-Founders".

If it really is a title of address, then it should be capitalized when and only when used as a title before the person's name. Thus, "The meeting was chaired by Co-Founder Jones", but "The meeting was chaired by one of our co-founders". (Well, it would also be capitalized when used as the first word in a sentence, etc.)

If it is capitalized, whether you should write "Co-Founder" or "Co-founder" ... my gut instict is "Co-Founder", but I don't know of any authoritative source to back that up. There's something of an analogy that when you have two-word titles, both words are capitalized, like we write "Vice President Jones", not "Vice president Jones". I think a hyphenated title would follow similar logic, but as I say, I don't have any independent confirmation on that.

Comment: I edited my question to include the intended use. Basically it's for business cards

Comment: In that case, I'd capitalize it because job titles on business cards are generally capitalized. You write "Joe Smith, Senior Accountant", not "Joe Smith, senior accountant".